# Regular expression messing up json_decode();

Tags: php, regex, json

I am using a file containing a json string to create request validations. One of the slices of JSON in one of my tests looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "pattern",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "pattern",
                "value": "^[\d]{2}$"
            }
        ]
    }
```

when you try to use json_decode() on this string however, you get a json syntax error. It has something to do with the content of the regular expression. Why and is there a way around this?

Comment: You should probably escape the backslash with another backslash `\\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash needs to be escaped:

```
  "value": "^[\\d]{2}$"
```

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) allows the following tokens in strings:

> - any-Unicode-character-except-`"`-or-`\`-or-control-character
> - `\"`
> - `\\`
> - `\/`
> - `\b`
> - `\f`
> - `\n`
> - `\r`
> - `\t`
> - `\u four-hex-digits`

`\d` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape out the `\`, as `\d` isn't a valid control character in JSON.