# Regex messing up json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

When I put this into a json checker, it's a valid json, but the json_decode in php gives a decode error.  json partial:

```
"regex":{
    "validator":"Regex",
    "options":{
        "pattern":"\/^[a-zA-Z\\.\\- ]+$\/",
        "messages":"Please use letters, spaces, period and dashes only"
    }
}
```

I looked at [Regular expression messing up json_decode();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638325/regular-expression-messing-up-json-decode) but that didn't help me.

Thanks!

Here is the entire json:

Comment: Which error code are you getting with `json_decode`?

Comment: json_decode() is returning null.  if i take out that pattern, it decodes fine.

Comment: Please see [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error) for error codes / messages if `json_decode` fails.

Comment: When *I* put this into a json checker, I get an error...

Comment: it's just a partial of the entire json but it's the problem area.  if you put enclosing {}, I get valid json from json checker.

Comment: Works fine when I drop your entire JSON into http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html...

Comment: functions-online must be escaping the regex control chars that php doesn't like, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$json = '{"regex":{
    "validator":"Regex",
    "options":{
        "pattern":"\\/^[a-zA-Z\\\\.\\\\- ]+$\\/",
        "messages":"Please use letters, spaces, period and dashes only"
    }
}
}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Notice the entire JSON string was encapsulated with `{}` and also notice all backslashes were escaped with another backslash (so where regex wants \ we have \\). This works perfect.

NOTE UPDATE:

Just `str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $json);` and you will be fine. Also, if this is submitted in a form it *SHOULD* be fine. I just submitted your entire JSON string through an HTML form and sent it directly to `json_decode` (without escaping) and it worked. This is because the browser escapes backslashes already. So long we are not defining the string within PHP it will be escaped (atleast backslashes)

Comment: `\\/` can be written as `\/` in single-quoted strings in PHP.

Comment: the double and quadruple backslashes solved my problem.  Thanks!